# PHP: Getting next full line and text after that line

Tags: php

If I have a text file formatted as such:

```
00:00:00 Text 1
00:00:01 Text 2
00:00:02 Text 3
00:00:03 Text 4
00:00:04 Text 5
00:00:05 Text 6
```

How would I create a PHP function to get all text after a specific time **starting from** the next line?

Example: Time 00:00:03 specified, fetch all lines from 00:00:04.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? `strpos()`, `substr()`?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: I've played around with strstr(), strpos(), things of the such, but I'm not sure how to skip to the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the PHP functions:

- [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)
- [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Essentially you will want to follow a process like:

1. Open file pointer to the file containing the text
2. Use fgets to pull a line at a time
3. Use substr to get the time, check if it matches
4. If doesn't match continue; if it does match set a flag and continue;
5. If flag has been met then skip substr check and do something with the data (at this point the data would be what you are expecting).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't homework or something is it?

One approach would be read the file, split by newline, loop until you find the line in question, then grab the rest of the array, recombine, return.

Lots of ways to do this, of course.

```
$contents = file_get_contents("/path/to/file.txt");
$lines = explode("\n",$contents);
for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    $time = substr($lines[$i],0,8);
    if( $time == "00:00:03" ) {
        array_splice($lines, 0, $i+1) //removes 0 -- $i from $lines
        return implode("\n", $lines);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just because I asked a entry-level question doesn't mean I'm doing homework.

Comment: Sorry.  I hope I'm not too cynical!

Comment: I understand, although I don't even know where people would get PHP as homework.